# Return the key that has the most records in the dictionary

Tags: python, list

I need to check in the dictionary which key has the greatest amount of data:

I have the following dictionary layout:

```
dic = {
    'ls1': [
        'value1',
        'value2',
        'value3'
    ],
    'ls2': [
        'value4',
        'value5',
        'value6',
        'value7'
    ],
    'ls3': [
        'value8',
        'value9'
    ]
}
```

I've already tried this:

```
item1 = dic['ls1']
item2 = dic['ls2']
item3 = dic['ls3']

if len(item1) > len(item2) and len(item1) > len(item3):
    print('ls1')
elif len(item2) > len(item1) and len(item2) > len(item3):
    print('ls2')
else:
    print('ls3')
```

But it's not nice to do it that way. Is there anything better than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `max()` with custom `key=`:

```py
dic = {
    "ls1": ["value1", "value2", "value3"],
    "ls2": ["value4", "value5", "value6", "value7"],
    "ls3": ["value8", "value9"],
}

print(max(dic, key=lambda k: len(dic[k])))
```

Prints:

```
ls2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
counts = list((len(v),k) for k,v in dic.items())
print(counts)
print(max(counts))
```

Answer (score 0):

see below

```
dic = {
    'ls1': [
        'value1',
        'value2',
        'value3'
    ],
    'ls2': [
        'value4',
        'value5',
        'value6',
        'value7'
    ],
    'ls3': [
        'value8',
        'value9'
    ]
}

data = sorted([(k, len(v)) for k, v in dic.items()], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(data[0])
```

output

```
('ls2', 4)
```